# Why is this battery level service failing to show notifications?

Tags: java, android, xml, service

I have to create a service that depending on the battery percentage shows a notification. The problem is that it does not work as it should.

```
public class Battery extends Service {

    BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiverLevel;
    Notification notification;
    Context context;
    int level;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    public void BatteryLevel(Context mContext) {


        notification = new Notification();

        batteryInfoReceiverLevel = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);

                if(level <=100) {
                //Show notification 01

                }  if(level == 100) {
                    //Show Notification 02 
                }
            }
        };
        mContext.registerReceiver(batteryInfoReceiverLevel, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)); 
    }
}
```

This service must start at boot, so I created this class

```
public class ServiceBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        intent = new Intent(context, Battery.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

In my manifest, in tag

```
<service android:name="Battery"></service>
    <receiver android:name="ServiceBoot">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And the relative permission RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED. Now, the As soon as you turn on the phone the service starts correctly but does not show any notifications even if the condition is true. I am sure that the variable level is NOT NULL.The strange thing is that if in any activity of my application using this code

```
Battery bat = new CheckBattery();
bat.BatteryLevel(getBaseContext());
```

works well because it shows the notification. Where is the problem then? How can I fix?

Comment: Where do you call BatteryLevel(Context) in your service?

Comment: So is this the problem?

Comment: Well if you don't invoke the method, how should the code be executed?

Comment: Also, `if(level <=100)` will always be called and `if(level == 100)` ignored since the `==` is already covered in the first `if`